# App crashes when updating an highlighted NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, crash, nsmenu

Heyho!
I've a little app running as `LSUIElement` with a `NSStatusItem`.
Sometimes the popupmenu's menuitems are updated by the code. But when the updated `NSMenuItem` (or its supermenu) is "highlighted" the app crashes without logging something.

Do you have any idea? Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you reproduce the crash while running in gdb?   Gdb works fine from the command line and I have often run GUI applications via gdb at the command line to catch the intermittent crash.

Once it crashes in gdb, use the `bt` command to grab the backtrace of the crash location.

Crashes of this nature -- intermittent -- are almost always caused by memory corruption, incorrect threading or over-releasing objects.   Have a look at your code and make sure you followed the Cocoa memory management guidelines.  If you are using threads, make sure you aren't diddling UI objects inappropriately from a non-main thread.

Comment: Mmh. It seems that I was "diddling UI objects inappropriately from a non-main thread". Thank you very much!

This helped:
(void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait